Is Apollo client polling 'long' or 'short'?
I can't see anything in the Apollo docs to suggest whether the Apollo client implements short or long polling - can someone please confirm(?)

If we are able to define a polling interval, it should be short polling right? Just to be clear i did not downvote

Also, won't long polling require support on the backend too. I don't think it is a front end only change. So I guess they mean short polling only

@TusharShahi thats what I thought, but wasn't sure. Seems that you can be judged on stackoverflow just for asking a simple question (to the down-voter) :(

Yeah, i guess this question needs upvotes and some answer so that the down-voter is happy :D Maybe a contributor at apollo will also answer, which will be the final word.

I would guess that the Apollo docs don't surface this kind of information because the devs would consider it to be abstracted away from end users. This isn't to say it's not good to know, though.
An easy way to check which type of polling is being used would be to open up a network inspector -- Wireguard and tcpdump are both good choices, though you do have to know how to use them at a basic level -- and inspect the traffic that way.
If you see slow requests consistently resulting in multiple back-and-forths, there's a good chance it's short polling.
If slow requests instead just involve one round trip, it's long-polling.
This SO answer has some details that might help you narrow down your search.

If you look at the source you'll see that a new timeout for your pollInterval is set after the last network request has returned.
https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/blob/d42d9e09f6e887d2e862784eb601a8bda5802f11/src/core/ObservableQuery.ts#L866-L879
I'm not sure if that qualifies as "short" or "long" here, but the time between two polled network requests with be the time it takes for one network request plus your pollInterval.

As mentioned in comments, there are hints that prove that internally polling (or short polling is used):

Long polling requires support on the backend and has to be implemented differently than most request-response mechanisms (eg: middleware lirary Express.js on Node). I don't think a frontend library will assume that in one of their default options.
pollingInterval is an option passed to useQuery so that also shows that this is short polling instead of long where there is no interval.

